# PHP while loop, even/odd rows returned

Tags: php, jquery, css

I have a PHP loop that displays data for a particular posting on my website.  What I want to do is dynamically assign  either and even/odd CSS class for the number of row that is returned.  For example,

```
first row returned - odd class
second row returned - even class
third row - odd class
```

This will allow me to assign different background colors to keep the data visually separate.

I should clarify - this data isn't being returned in a table.

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo "
    <div class=\"songContainer\" id=\"" . $row['trackid'] . "\">
```

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried so far? Please post some code. Please use the search function of the site (because this looks like a duplicate question).

Comment: Quicker to have a frontend jquery code like datatables.com - google `jquery table display plugin`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php: how to add odd/even loop in array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403213/php-how-to-add-odd-even-loop-in-array)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Depending on which browsers you have to target, you could just do that with CSS:

```
.mytable tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: #FFF; }
.mytable tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #EEE; }
```

You can even do more complex things with this pseudo-class: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/nthchild.html

If you really need PHP, use a modulo:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($arr as $val) {
    if (0 == $i % 2) {
        // even
    }
    else {
        // odd
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

nth-child class is supported in CSS3 like this.

```
table tr:nth-child(even) td{

}

table tr:nth-child(odd) td{

}
```

But if you're to support older ones too, you have no choice but to generate class names by PHP.

Answer (score 1):

```
$num_rows = 0;
$current_class = "";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $current_class = "class_odd";
    if($num_rows % 2 == 0){
        $current_class = "class_even";
    }

    $num_rows++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this jQuery:

```
$("tr:nth-child(2n)").addClass("even")
  .prev().addClass("odd");
```

It selects every second `tr` element and adds an even class to it. Then it selects the previous `tr` element and adds an odd class to it.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/fA2pC/).

Answer (score 0):

When using php you can use this instead of modulo suggested by Pascal:

```
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($arr as $val) {
        if ( $i = 1 - $i ) {
            // even
        }
        else {
            // odd
        }
    }
```