# add row number and odd/even class to php table

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php: how to add odd/even loop in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403213/php-how-to-add-odd-even-loop-in-array)

I am generating a table in php with the below code.

```
<?PHP
while ($row = $mydata->fetch())
{
  $tests[] = array(
  'a' => $row['a'], 
  'b' => $row['b']
  )
  ;
}

?>
```

Then the output code

```
<table>
  <tbody>
  <tr><th>#</th><th>a</th><th>b</th></tr>
  <?php foreach ($tests as $test): ?>
    <tr class="">
        <td></td>
        <td><?php htmlout($test['a']); ?></td>
        <td><?php htmlout($test['b']); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

which outputs

```
<table>
  <tbody>
  <tr><th>#</th><th>a</th><th>b</th></tr>
    <tr class="">
        <td></td><td>a content</td><td>b content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
        <td></td><td>a content</td><td>b content</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

htmlout is the below custom function.

```
<?php
function html($text)
{
return htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
function htmlout($text)
{
echo html($text);
}
?>
```

This is all working well but I can't work out two things here.

1. I want my rows to generate `<tr class="odd">` and `<tr class="even">` on alternate rows
2. I want the first `<td></td>` within the `<tr>` to count show the row number of the data eg `<td>1</td>` in the first `<tr class=""> <td>2</td>` in the second etc.

I have looked at numerous examples such as this

```
$count = 1;
while ($count <= 10)
{
echo "$count ";
++$count;
}
```

But can't work out how to implent it into my example or maybe I should use another method.  I understand I can do the table rows in jQuery and in some browsers with css3 but would prefer a php solution in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
<?php foreach ($tests as $i => $test): ?>
    <?php $class = ($i % 2 == 0) ? 'even' : 'odd'; ?>
    <tr class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
        <td><?php echo $i + 1; ?></td>
        <td><?php htmlout($test['a']); ?></td>
        <td><?php htmlout($test['b']); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This leverages the fact that the array keeps a numerical index `$i`. So, the row number is really `$i + 1`, which we put into the first column. Then, we determine if the current row is even or odd based on whether or not `$i` is divisible by 2. If `$i` is divisible by 2, it's an even row, otherwise it's an odd row. We save the class string in `$class`, and put it in the `<tr>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is a add a loop counter.

```
<?php $counter = 0 ?>
<table>
  <tbody>
  <tr><th>#</th><th>a</th><th>b</th></tr>
  <?php foreach ($tests as $test): ?>
    <tr class="<?= ($counter % 2 == 0) ? 'even' : 'odd' ?>">
        <td><?php echo ($counter+1) ?></td>
        <td><?php htmlout($test['a']); ?></td>
        <td><?php htmlout($test['b']); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php $counter++ ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this is probably to switch from the foreach statement to a for loop. Using the modulus operator on the counter should work nicely for you.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
  <tr><th>#</th><th>a</th><th>b</th></tr>
  <?php for( $counter = 0; $counter < count( $tests ); $tests++ ): ?>
    <tr class="<? ( $counter % 2 ) ? echo "even" : echo "odd"; ?>">
        <td><? echo $counter + 1; ?></td>
        <td><?php htmlout($tests[$counter]['a']); ?></td>
        <td><?php htmlout($tests[$counter]['b']); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endfor; ?>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```