# Highlight every other row of a table in a foreach loop and highlight columns depending on value of row

Tags: php, html, foreach, html-table, highlight

I had a really long description written for my problem, but I've progressed and have managed to get it partially working... I basically want every other row in a table to be a different color - and to highlight certain rows if they meet a condition that I set.

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $style = null;
        while (($values = fgetcsv($handle, 0, '|')) !== false) {
                $comment_lines = $values[6];
                $priority      = $values[7];
                $time_worked   = $values[11];
                $var_X  = strpos($priority, '1');
                $var_C1 = strpos($comment_lines, 'CCB');
                $var_C2 = strpos($comment_lines, 'CEB');
                $var_U  = empty($time_worked);
        }

        if (empty($values[0]) && count($values) === 1) {
                continue;
        }
    if (strlen($var_X)) {
        echo '<tr class="gradeX">';
        foreach ($values AS $index => $value) {
                echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>' ;
        }
    } else if ($var_C1 !== false) {
        echo '<tr class="gradeC">';
        foreach ($values AS $index => $value) {
                echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>' ;
        }
    } else if ($var_C2 !== false) {
        echo '<tr class="gradeC">';
        foreach ($values AS $index => $value) {
                echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>' ;
        }
    } else if ($var_U !== false) {
        echo '<tr class="gradeU">';
        foreach ($values AS $index => $value) {
                echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>' ;
        }
    } else if ($odd) {
        $odd = !$odd;
        echo '<tr class="even gradeA">';
        foreach ($values AS $index => $value) {
                echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>' ;
        }
    } else {
        $odd = !$odd;
        echo '<tr class="odd gradeA">';
        foreach ($values AS $index => $value) {
                echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>' ;
        }
    }
                echo '</tr>';
}
```

Right now, only the 'every other' is working. I can't get the gradeX, gradeC and gradeU to show anything...

EDIT:

This is the working code, cheers.

```
while (($values = fgetcsv($handle, 0, '|')) !== false) {
        $style = null;
        $comment_lines = $values[6];
        $priority      = $values[7];
        $time_worked   = $values[11];
        $var_X  = strpos($priority, '1');
        $var_C1 = strpos($comment_lines, 'CCB');
        $var_C2 = strpos($comment_lines, 'CEB');
        $var_U  = empty($time_worked);

        if (empty($values[0]) && count($values) === 1) {
                continue;
        }

        if ($var_X !==false) {
                echo '<tr class="gradeX">';
        } elseif ($var_C1 !== false) {
                echo '<tr class="gradeC">';
        } elseif ($var_C2 !== false) {
                echo '<tr class="gradeC">';
        } elseif ($var_U !== false) {
                echo '<tr class="gradeU">';
        } else {
                //nothing
        }

        foreach ($values as $index => $value) {
                echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
        }

        echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: I think I will have to check the $values array's 5th, 6th, and 10th indexes in the loop... The 5th = P column, 6th = Comment, 10th = Time Worked... Maybe I can create a $style variable which would get different values depending on the $values[5], $values[6], and $values[10] current content? I guess the $style variable should go into the echo line: "echo '<tr><td style="'.$style.'">Cell data</td></tr>';" .

Comment: Another thing that I might want to do is count the rows somehow to know which is even or odd... Should this be another if statement inside the loop? Would this somehow also be able to change the value of $style? Perhaps an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop you need to add a counter to identify whether you're currently on an 'even' or an 'odd' iteration, and then add either class 'odd' or 'even' into the  as you output it.

There's a related question already on here that covers that here: [php: how to add odd/even loop in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403213/php-how-to-add-odd-even-loop-in-array)

The other parts should be fairly easy by using if statements to check if the relevant data exists or not.

For example, [strlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) will tell you whether a variable has length or not (to put out 'gradeX'), and [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) will allow you to check if a varibale contains a string (for 'gradeC').

Comment: I am looking into this - I'm trying to figure out how to actually use the even/odd count that the first link describes.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think I need a bit more direction than this - I am still quite novice with PHP.

Comment: Take a look at the link I sent over to you.  That should help you out with the loop count: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403213/php-how-to-add-odd-even-loop-in-array  The rest of it's just a case of looking at the functions I included (strlen and strpos) - the documentation for these two is great, plenty of examples to help you on your way!

Comment: OK - I have every other working - but not the coloring. I added the current code to my details above.

Comment: Great news that you've managed to get so much of it working!  With the odd/even colouring: it's all based on the assumption that there is a count within the loop.  Usually you would do this by declaring $i and then adding to it each loop (like this: for($i=0;$i<$blah;$i++)).  Within the loop you can then check if odd or even based on the number $i is set to (it will start at zero and go up each iteration).  Have another look at the top answer on this question, particularly where it checks if odd (if($i&1){) or not.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I got the last bit of it working - you were by far the most helpful. Answer 'accepted'. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you can target IE later than IE8 and forget about IE8, you can use CSS3:

```
 tr:nth-child(odd) {
     background-color: #EEEEEE;
 }

 tr:nth-child(even) {
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
 }
```

Comment: I will pretty much be using Chrome/Firefox for these.